# How can I extract sentences from any search engine?

Tags: search

For people who are learning a foreign language it is very helpful to see usage of particular words in a sentence. For example you want to see different inflections of a verb. I used to look at usage of words in imdb > quotes search section, it almost stores all Hollywood movies' scriptures. I want to make a command line tool to search any word in a search engine and display results in ordered sentence list. I found a few perl script to parse a text into sentences. How can I extract sentences from any search engine and list them in sentences as in jukuu.com bilingual sentence searcher?

Comment: I just found a useful source on that page  [link](http://lilyx.net/2011/07/21/extracting-multilingual-parallel-senteces-from-tatoeba-com/) it's tatoeba [link](http://tatoeba.org)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example with [INDB, Prisoner](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1392214/?ref_=hm_cht_t1).

Command

```
/tmp$ wget http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1392214/?ref_=hm_cht_t1
```

This will show some things ...

```
--14:17:11--  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1392214/?ref_=hm_cht_t1
           => `index.html?ref_=hm_cht_t1'
Resolving www.imdb.com... 72.21.215.52
Connecting to www.imdb.com|72.21.215.52|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]

    [                                        ] 186,103      389.18K/s

14:17:12 (388.45 KB/s) - `index.html?ref_=hm_cht_t1' saved [186103]
```

Result:

```
~/tmp$ ls
index.html?ref_=hm_cht_t1
```

And now you can scan the file...

```
grep Directed\ by index.html\?ref_\=hm_cht_t1
<meta name="description" content="Directed by Denis Villeneuve.  With Hugh Jackman, Jake Gyllenhaal, Viola Davis, Melissa Leo. When Keller Dover's daughter and her friend go missing, he takes matters into his own hands as the police pursue multiple leads and the pressure mounts. But just how far will this desperate father go to protect his family?" />
<meta property="og:description" content="Directed by Denis Villeneuve.  With Hugh Jackman, Jake Gyllenhaal, Viola Davis, Melissa Leo. When Keller Dover's daughter and her friend go missing, he takes matters into his own hands as the police pursue multiple leads and the pressure mounts. But just how far will this desperate father go to protect his family?" />
```

---

Above example is the core for how you can do it more elaborate: have a user type in something (s)he wants to search, wget google with that word. Scan those results for URLs, wget those URLs, extract content from those results and present those to that user.

Comment: Thank you Rinzwind for your post and idea you shared. Honestly I was confused how to achieve that and you gave an idea about how to do that. Yet I can't figure out how to do that in google's case. When I search for something in google, it lists only half of th  sentence most of the time that it's not suitable for parsibg into sentences.